# Searching in polygons in sphinx using Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have setup thinking sphinx for real-time indexing and It works very well and search with geodist as well.But now I want to search the records within polygon.

Sphinx documentation explains it very well at [Geo-distance searching](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/07/02/geo-distances-with-sphinx/)

now I want to use this functionality using thinking sphinx.
Thinking sphinx does explain about **geodist** search [Here](http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/geosearching.html)
But It does not state how to search within a polygon.

Can any one help me here to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking Sphinx doesn't have anything inbuilt to provide a neat interface for the polygon searching, but it's certainly possible to use the functionality.

You'll want to generate the SphinxQL `SELECT` clause that you'd like, filter on it accordingly, and/or you can access your custom attributes using the `AttributesPane`. The following code is hopefully clear:

```
search = Model.search("foo",
  :select => "*, CONTAINS(GEOPOLY2D(...), ...) AS inside",
  :with   => {:inside => true}
); ""
search.context[:panes] << ThinkingSphinx::Panes::AttributesPane
search.collect { |instance| instance.sphinx_attributes["inside"] }
```

The `; ""` at the end of the first statement is only needed when running this in IRB or a Rails console - you want to avoid calling `search` in a way that evaluates the results until you've added the pane in. Search results are normally lazily loaded, but IRB calls `inspect` to print statement results which removes the lazy advantage.

Panes are discussed in [a blog post I wrote](http://freelancing-gods.com/2013/07/09/rewriting-thinking-sphinx-middleware-glazes-and-panes.html), and the source code for the [AttributesPane](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/blob/develop/lib/thinking_sphinx/panes/attributes_pane.rb) class is very simple. You may also want to write a custom middleware class that uses your own options and translates them into the polygon functions - the [Geographer](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/blob/develop/lib/thinking_sphinx/middlewares/geographer.rb) class (which is what translates `:geo` into `GEODIST`) is a good reference for that.

Comment: Thanks Pat, I really appreciate the efforts your are putting to make TS a better platform. 
I already read the blog post regarding middleware. I went through the source code and came to no that there is not a straight way to use polygon like `geodist` So used the above mentioned method to make it work temporarily.

Comment: I also wanted to know about the dynamic attributes like the one you mentioned above. So both of my queries resolved. as a suggestion I think you can mention the above method to use dynamic attributes and polygon based search in the documentation section of thinking sphinx. 
I kind of read the whole documentation to find it but could not find it.
Thanks again for your help